# Why did the Green Lanterns reject Guy Gardner in the selection process of Justice League?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, young-justice

In Young Justice Season 1, Justice League vote for addition of new members to the team and have so many arguments over Red Arrow, Captain Marvel etc. But when Guy Gardner's name was proposed both Green Lanterns (Hal Jordan and John Stewart) rejected the idea straight forward without specifying any reason at all.

I am not much familiar with  Guy Gardner version of Green Lantern but I supposed he have same ring with similar power then why he is rejected like this? And why there was no cross argument form any non Green Lantern JL superhero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Station Eight - Ask Greg](http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/) has a few tidbits.

It is possible they turned him down because he was in a coma until very recently.

> **Asker:**  How long has Guy  Gardner  been active as a Green Lantern?
>   **Greg:** Well, this is more complicated. Guy first became a Green Lantern seven years before Team Year Zero. Then came the coma. Guy then emerged from his coma in March of Team Year Zero. - [#17729](http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/search.php?qid=17729)

**But it appears to be some kind of personality conflict.**

> **Asker:** Why were Hal Jordan and John  Stewart  so adamant to cut short any discussion on Guy Gardner's induction in the Justice League?
>   **Greg:** They're not fond of his... style. - [#15704](http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/search.php?qid=15704)

Then there is the absurd.

> **Asker:** When the other Lanterns said "No" regarding Guy  Gardner , was it because of his good looks, his chiseled abs, or because they knew his ring-slinging skills would make them obsolete? All of the above is an absolutely acceptable answer.
>   **Greg:** I'll stick with "Um."

They did eventually ask him to join though.

> **Asker:** During the time skip, has the Justice League issue another recruitment?
>   **Greg:**  I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I think it's clear that they've added members, specifically Blue Beetle (Ted Kord, since deceased), Black Lightning, Green Lantern (Guy  Gardner ), Zatanna and Rocket. The first three were inducted together sometime during the time skip, the last two were inducted together shortly before the start of Season Two. - [#17474](http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/search.php?qid=17474)

Answer (score 3):

Guy Gardner... is an asshole. And hates batman. And doesn't play well with anyone. Not to say he isn't a good guy, or loveable, but really, he's a jerk with anger issues. Quick to through a punch.

[image]

Comment: Sound like an interesting character.